# Getting The Latest Record Of Table By Date And Group By ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i have a problem of how to output the latest data of **"reading_timesent"** by using **max(Date)**, And Also Include the other column where the latest date, and remove redundant data using distinct or group i don't know whats my problem here's the sample img and data

**Patient table**
[image]
**Reading Table**
[image]
**Inner Join table**
[image]
**Expected Output**
[image]

[JSFIDDLE SAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51c20c/20)

```
SELECT * FROM Patients P
INNER JOIN Reading R ON R.patient_ID = P.patient_ID
```

Comment: Please include your data in the question.  No one can/should have to open those links.

Comment: Just put `order by reading_timesent DESC` in the end of the query and you'll be good to go.

Comment: i want to get the latest "reading_timesent" and also get the other column of reading

Comment: @the.salman.a no imean i want to get the latest time_send and also remove the redundant data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *,
    (
        SELECT reading_ID 
        FROM Reading 
        WHERE Reading.patient_ID = p.patient_ID 
        ORDER BY reading_timesent DESC
        LIMIT 1
     ) AS newestReadingID
     FROM Patients p
) AS subquery
JOIN Reading ON subquery.newestReadingID = Reading.reading_ID
```

Comment: i already do that but i want to include also the reading date like reading_temp,reading_oxygenstat,reading_pulserate

Comment: But they could be different. Which one of the data do you want to display and following which rules?

Comment: the query you do is correct because it output the latest reading_timesent, but add the other column of reading_temp, reading_oxygenstat, reading_pulserate

Comment: Okay, guess I understood what you mean. Try the edit.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 reading_ID FROM Reading WHERE Reading.patient_ID = Patients.' at line 5

Comment: Sorry my fault. Please try again

Comment: haha just use this fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51c20c/20 and include this to your answer

Comment: Okay, that helped. Please give it another try

Comment: Thanks Dude :) you save my ass

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for the confusion. It's alway hard to write queries without a database to test on ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a correlated subquery for a condition in the ON clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM Patients P
INNER JOIN Reading R
  ON  R.patient_ID = P.patient_ID
  AND R.reading_timesent = (
          SELECT MAX(R2.reading_timesent)
          FROM Reading R2
          WHERE R2.patient_ID = P.patient_ID
      )
```

Another way:

```
SELECT P.*, R.*
FROM (
  SELECT patient_ID, MAX(reading_timesent) as reading_timesent
  FROM Reading
  GROUP BY patient_ID
) X
JOIN Patients P USING (patient_ID)
JOIN Reading  R USING (patient_ID, reading_timesent)
```

Usually I would use the AUTO_INCREMENT column instead of a TIMESTAMP column for similar tasks. But that is not always applicable.

Comment: nc simple answer

Comment: I like that too, It's much shorter ;-)